# How to hide / show tr tag in table without change the width and sort of cells

Tags: javascript, html, togglebutton

Hi i would hide / show one row from table
But when click to show row again the design change
The columns of the hidden row shrink under one column of first row
My code

```js
function toggle(tr_id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(tr_id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
  <table class="table table-resposive ">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>address</td>
      <td>age</td>
      <td><a onclick="toggle('edit');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">edit</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="edit">
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display="table-row"`

```
function toggle(tr_id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(tr_id);
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'table-row';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are displaying the row as block. Try use `visibility == "hidden"` instead of `display`

EDIT : Or you can use `display = "table-row"` as show below. The use `visibility == "hidden"` will hide the row, but it will still take up the same space as before.

```
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "table-row";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

```js
function toggle(tr_id)
{
  var x = document.getElementById(tr_id);
    if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
        x.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
<table class="table table-resposive ">
<tr> 
<td>name</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>age</td>
<td><a onclick="toggle('edit2');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">edit</a></td>

</tr>

 <tr id="edit1">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>

 <tr id="edit2">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>

 <tr id="edit3">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Snippet 2 :**

```js
function toggle(tr_id)
{
  var x = document.getElementById(tr_id);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "table-row";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
<table class="table table-resposive ">
<tr> 
<td>name</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>age</td>
<td><a onclick="toggle('edit2');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">edit</a></td>

</tr>

 <tr id="edit1">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>

 <tr id="edit2">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>

 <tr id="edit3">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What if there is more than one row

Comment: @AbbasMohammed Check the updated answer. I have inserted 2 snippets, so that you can check the behavior of both

Comment: I think you need second one using `display = "table-row"`

Answer (score 0):

set your `td` css with fixed width

```js
function toggle(tr_id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(tr_id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
td {
 width: 140px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
  <table class="table table-resposive ">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>address</td>
      <td>age</td>
      <td><a onclick="toggle('edit');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">edit</a></td>

    </tr>

    <tr id="edit">
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

how to make row move to top

```js
function toggle(tr_id)
{
  var x = document.getElementById(tr_id);
    if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
        x.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
<table class="table table-resposive ">
<tr> 
<td>name</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>age</td>
<td><a onclick="toggle('edit');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">edit</a></td>

</tr>

 <tr id="edit">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>
    <tr> 
<td>name</td>
<td>address</td>
<td>age</td>
<td><a onclick="toggle('edit1');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">edit</a></td>

</tr>

 <tr id="edit1">
 <td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><input type="text"     ></td>
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: also achieved by using `display = "table-row"`

Answer (score 0):

the default value of `display` propery of `tr` is `table-row` but not `block`,so the design is changed.

You should replace 'block' with 'table-row'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plain JavaScript way of doing toggle:

```js
function toggle(_id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(_id);
  x.classList.toggle("hide-me");
}
```

```css
.hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
  <table class="table table-resposive ">
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>address</td>
      <td>age</td>
      <td><a onclick="toggle('edit');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="edit">
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><input type="text"></td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-success">save</a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```